# How to replace the avatar image by a div in the Ionic List-Item Directive?

Tags: html, css, angularjs, ionic-framework

The ionic framework offers a [directive](http://ionicframework.com/docs/components/%23item-avatars)
 to create lists with list items and avatars on the left using the following code:

```
<div class="list">
 <a class="item item-avatar" href="#">
      <img src="venkman.jpg">
      <h2>Venkman</h2>
      <p>Back off, man. I'm a scientist.</p>
    </a>
</div>
```

However, the avators need to be an image (looks like it searches for images). How can we replace this image by a custom div or just text?

Answer (score 7):

Solved it, use item-icon-left!

```
<a class="item item-icon-left" href="#">
  <i class="icon ion-home"></i>
  <h2>Venkman</h2>
  <p>Back off, man. I'm a scientist.</p>
</a>
```

Comment: Thanks for this :)